# Alternative for window.url in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

Is there any alternative for

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
```

for Safari 5 and below?? Am trying to preview the image uploaded by the user using following snippet :

```
var file = jQuery('#brandImageUpload').prop("files")[0];
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL ;
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
$('#ibrandImage').attr('src', blobURL);
$('#brandImage').slideDown();
$(this).slideUp();
```

But window.URL returns undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to **[`http://caniuse.com`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls)**, this functionality is simply not supported by Safari 5.1 and below.

It is important to understand that it is not supported by either IE9 and below, Opera Mini and some other minor desktop and mobile browsers. So, probably, it is better to avoid using it.

Comment: I tried this because fileReader was not recognised in safari 5 and below.Could you suggest me any idea to preview the image selected by user other than these??

Comment: @dev If both `FileReader` and `URL` are not working in Safari 5-, then no.  I don't know any way to do this without it.

Comment: [CIU doesn't currently have a support table for the URL Standard.](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/1312)