# How to use Window.URL or Webkit.URL in safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

How can I solve the issue for `var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;`
As it does not working in Safari browser.
I debug the code but it showing undefined and there is no window.URL || webkit.URL in safari browser as it is in Chrome and Firefox browsers.
Is there any way that I can use URL constructor and download the image?
I am using following createObjectURL but it isn't working:

`var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);`

Is there any other solution?

Comment: This Question is Duplicate
Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390092/alternative-for-window-url-in-safari

Comment: Which Safari version ? [It is supported since v8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=url) (2014). All previous versions are obsoletes and dangerous, since they contain a lot of security breaches. And if you are using Safari for windows, like I fear you do, stop right now ; Apple did stop supporting this thing in 2012 !

Comment: thank u @Kaiido. Will try with your suggestion